# DataTable.Rows returns second row in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, oledb

I'm reading Excel sheet using `OleDbDataReader` and convert it to a `Datatable`.
The first few columns row in the Excel sheet tells information about the details of excel.

Ex:

```
Month ---- First Row
Year --- Second Row
Payment ---THird row
```

Balance rows in that Excel sheet have salary details of all employees.

I coded like below:

```
OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();    

DataTable dtable = new DataTable(); 
dtable.Load(odr);

if (dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
{                             
    DataRow row = dtable.Rows[0];
    sMonth = row[2].ToString();
    row = dtable.Rows[1];
    sYear = row[2].ToString();
    row = dtable.Rows[2];
    sPayDate = row[2].ToString();         

    ///Salary details
    for (int i = 6; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {        
        row = dtable.Rows[i];
        colName = odr[1].ToString();
        colBasic = row[9].ToString();
        colHRA = row[10].ToString();
        ......
    }
}
```

But

```
DataRow row = dtable.Rows[0];
```

returns the second row. (i.e) Year Details

I could not get month details in first row.

Comment: Show the query and the connection string.

Comment: What is the sql statement you're executing? Did you remember to sort the resultset correctly/at all? I doubt that `dtable.Rows[0]` returns the second row *of the ones that was retrieved* but that it returns the second row *according to what you expected*, that I don't doubt. So does `querry` contain an `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: can you show the sample input file, perhaps a screenshot of the input excel file.

Comment: Is `HDR=YES`? and if so, it looks like first row is taken as the header.

Comment: string path = "C:\\Payslip.xls";
            string querry = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = '" + path + "'" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";
            conn.Open();

Comment: Now i changed HDR=No, it works now.  Thank you 'aspiring'

Comment: Then can I post it as an answer?

Comment: Consider using  Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead of Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 as it's kinda old now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your connection string's `HDR=YES` property to `NO` as per my comment.

```
conn.ConnectionString = 
@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = '" + path + "'" + 
@";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;
TypeGuessRows=0""";
```

["HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/).